# Difference between "racisé" and "racialisé" ?

Tags: sens, différence

From "dictionnary" definition, both mean more or less the same, but I vaguely remember that the "intent" behind each usage differ.
I haven't found more information about that online.

So the question is : What are the "deep" differences between "racisé" and "racialisé"?

Comment: https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/racis%C3%A9 — https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/racialis%C3%A9 sont inconnus dans ce dictionnaire de référence. Les néologismes avec le mot *race* sont à manier avec [une très grande] précaution.

Comment: Le TLFi n'est plus mis à jour depuis 1994... Même un mot comme "internet" n'y est pas repris, qu'il est difficile d'encore qualifier de néologisme.

Comment: @Greg — Dans sa réponse, *LPH* donne des références plus anciennes, *BBBreiz* donne des dates antérieures et développe mon commentaire.

Comment: Tout à fait, j'attire simplement l'attention sur le fait que le TLF est une référence malheureusement limitée pour tout le vocabulaire né ou modifié après 1990 (même en 1994, il avait déjà un sacré train de retard...)

Comment: @Greg … et a-t-on espoir de voir des mises à jour ou de le voir intégré dans une base d’intelligence artificielle, comme celle utilisée par DeepL ?

Comment: J'en doute: voici ce qu'indique le site du TLFi: Avertissement : la rédaction du TLF est terminée depuis 1994 et la plupart des contributeurs ont quitté le laboratoire. Il n’a pas vocation à être mis à jour. Cette ressource, qui ne fait pas l’objet d’une veille lexicographique, est donc close « en l’état ». Il est donc tout à fait naturel que les définitions qui s’y trouvent ne rendent pas compte des évolutions de la société.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selon [la ligue des droits et libertés](https://liguedesdroits.ca/lexique/personne-racisee-ou-racialisee/) il n'y a aucune différence, ces deux mots sont synonymes.

Voici une autre [source](https://mediateur.radiofrance.fr/infos/racialise-la-reponse-de-iannis-roder/) selon laquelle les deux mots sont synonymes.

- *C’est donc à cette époque qu’est réintroduit le terme « race » décliné à l’aide de néologismes comme « racialisé », puis son synonyme « racisé ».*

Dans cette [troisième source](https://mouvements.info/prendre-au-serieux-les-recherches-sur-les-rapports-sociaux-de-race/) (Prendre au sérieux les recherches sur les rapports sociaux de race), de même, aucune différence n'est reconnue.

- *La racialisation (Fanon 2002 [1961] : 202) ou racisation (Guillaumin 1972 : 161) se réfère avant tout à un acte d’assignation informé par l’idéologie raciste. Le concept de racialisation désigne ensuite, plus largement, un processus socialement construit de catégorisation qui altérise et infériorise un groupe (Mazouz 2017 : 15). L’idée de racialisation est donc indissociable de celle de hiérarchie[1]. Des personnes peuvent ainsi être qualifiées de l’adjectif « racisé » ou « racialisé » lorsqu’elles subissent l’un ou l’autre de ces processus.*

La tendance qui porterait à considérer qu'il y aurait une différence doit être très minoritaire.

Answer (score -2):

Il est important de souligner qu'en vérité, les adjectifs "*racisé*" et "*racialisé*" n'existent pas réellement en langue française, personne n'est donc en mesure de définir une différence de sens entre ces deux néologismes ayant moins de vingt ans et créés par des idéologies douteuses nées de la convergence de la sociologie et de l'obsession "*antiraciste*" qui caractérise la pensée politique depuis une trentaine d'années.

Chacun peut donc leur prêter le sens qu'il veut, puisque ces mots n'ont pas de véritable existence au point de vue académique. Il serait donc vain, en l'absence de définition officielle, de prétendre leur assigner des sens clairement distincts.

Comment: "Dire qu'un mot n'existe pas parce qu'il n'est pas au dictionnaire, c'est comme dire qu'un oiseau qui picore dans mon jardin n'existe pas parce qu'il n'est pas dans mon guide ornithologique" (lu quelque part):

Comment: @Greg … ""Dire qu'un mot n'existe pas ***véritablement*** parce qu'il n'est pas au dictionnaire, c'est comme dire qu'un oiseau qui picore dans mon jardin n'existe pas ***dans mon vocabulaire*** parce  qu'il n'est pas dans mon guide ornithologique"

Comment: Mais comment décide-t-on qu'un mot existe "véritablement" ? Il est utilisé depuis 20 ans, provenant de la sociologie, puis entré dans certains contextes plus "politiques". On peut penser qu'il est alors mal utilisé ou à tort et à travers, mais pourquoi affirmer qu'il "n'existe pas réellement" ? On le lit et on l'entend, alors oui, il existe bel et bien. Pas besoin que l'Académie française ou un dictionnaire entérine l'existence d'un mot pour qu'il existe et qu'il ait un sens.

Comment: @Greg — Un mot existe "véritablement", quand il est référencé dans un dictionnaire spécialisé ou un lexique adopté par une autorité compétente. Pour les mots concernés, aucun dictionnaire sociologique reconnu par les spécialistes n’a été relevé par LPH. Bon nombre de néologismes ou de mots franglais ont fini par entrer dans la langue (ou être rejetés et remplacés par de mots francisés, comme *courriel*), Ce n’est pas parce qu’un néologisme a été créé qu’il sera repris par tous,  il peut rester très spécifique à une époque et remplacé par une autre expression ensuite …

Comment: @Greg … sans devenir *véritable*, c’est-à-dire "vivant" dans sa sphère d’étude plus de quelques années, il est dans la même situation que les mots rejetés des dictionnaires, car inutilisés. Et la réponse de BBBreiz stipule bien que l’on ne peut pas vraiment les différencier sans définition reconnue par d’autres personnes que leurs auteurs qui peuvent apporter des nuances, ou la tautologie comme cela semble l’être dans la réponse ci-dessus.